# Grouping of PARTITION BY / GROUP BY only until next section to obtain a list of sections

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this:

| id | section |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 3 | 7 |
| 4 | 7 |
| 5 | 6 |

and would like to obtain a grouped list that says

| section | section_nr | first_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 1 | 1 |
| 7 | 2 | 3 |
| 6 | 3 | 5 |

Using ROW_NUMBER twice I am able to obtain something close:

```
SELECT section, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS section_nr, id as first_id
FROM (
  SELECT id, section, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY section ORDER BY id) AS nr_within
  FROM X
)
WHERE nr_within = 1
```

| section | section_nr | first_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 1 | 1 |
| 7 | 2 | 3 |

... but of course the second section 6 is missing, since PARTITION BY groups all section=6 together. Is it somehow possible to only group until the next section?

More generally (regarding GROUP BY instead of PARTITION BY), is there a simple solution to group (1,1,2,2,1) to (1,2,1) instead of (1,2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical gaps and islands problem that can be solved like this:

```
with u as
(select id, section, 
case when section = lag(section) over(order by id) then 0 else 1 end as grp
from X),
v as
(select id, 
section, 
sum(grp) over(order by id) as section_nr
from u)
select section,
section_nr,
min(id) as first_id
from v
group by section, section_nr;
```

Basically you keep tabs in a column where there is a change in `section` by comparing current `section` to `section` from the row above (ordered by id). Whenever there is a change, set this column to 1, when no change set it to 0. The rolling sum of this column will be the section number. Getting `first_id` is a simple matter of using `group by`.

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=bd1ee65403f029571b9ec6b2fccb5bec)

Answer (score 1):

That's a classic.

P.S.
If `id` is indeed a series of integers without gaps, we can use it instead of `rn`

```
select    section
         ,row_number() over (order by min(id)) as section_nr
         ,min(id)                              as first_id

from      (select id
                 ,section
                 ,row_number() over (order by id)                      as rn
                 ,row_number() over (partition by section order by id) as rn_section
           
           from   X
          )

group by  section
         ,rn - rn_section
```

| SECTION | SECTION_NR | FIRST_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 1 | 1 |
| 7 | 2 | 3 |
| 6 | 3 | 5 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=ddf42f66ffa2ec624de11daf1867df7e)